# I somehow deleted my Desktop from nautilus places

Tags: 14.04, gnome, nautilus

I somehow deleted my Desktop from nautilus places, it does not show in the places part of Nautilus anymore as you can see from the picture.

[image: Nautilus places]

And also now my Desktop lists the contents of my home folder, not the Desktop folder. How can I fix this? I use Ubuntu 14.04 and GNOME 3.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Edit the .config/user-dirs.dirs file by pasting this in a terminal:

```
gedit ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs
```

You will see text that looks like this:

```
# This file is written by xdg-user-dirs-update
# If you want to change or add directories, just edit the line you're
# interested in. All local changes will be retained on the next run
# Format is XDG_xxx_DIR="$HOME/yyy", where yyy is a shell-escaped
# homedir-relative path, or XDG_xxx_DIR="/yyy", where /yyy is an
# absolute path. No other format is supported.
# 
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="/data/downloads"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="/data/drive"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="/data/music"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="/data/pictures"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="/data/videos"
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="/data/desktop"
```

The `XDG_DESKTOP_DIR=` entry should be equal to your desktop folder (probably "$HOME/Desktop"). If it is missing, just type it in and save the file. Reboot and it should be back.

Comment: You can also use this file to set custom paths to the places links in Nautilus. For example, I've put almost all of my data on a different hard mounted on /data/ and you only need to specify the path in this file and when you click on the specific place it will take you there.

Comment: How could I add a custom folder there with an icon associated?