# Accidentally moved the Desktop to nowhere and it's gone even on restart

Tags: .desktop, mv

Damn! That's why someone said once, "Don't do other things while you are hungry". Basically, I was hungry and at that point of time I had to move a directory inside Desktop to another directory.

What I should have done:

```
mv Desktop/"directory1" /"directory2"
```

What I did:

```
mv Desktop/ ls (ls being the second argument)
```

I don't know why I did that. But it's already done and it's gone!

Now all I can see on my violet ubuntu Wallpaper are all the files and stuffs of my Home Directory and my Desktop is gone and moved to where, I don't know.

It's like, "Where do people go after they die?"

Is it possible to get back my Desktop somehow? Anyhow?

Comment: Off the top of my head, try `# find / -name Desktop*` and see what comes up

Comment: Are you sure you didn't type `mv Desktop /` (move `Desktop` to the filesystem root directory `/`) - the command `mv Desktop/` should have just errored out with a message like `mv: missing destination file operand after ‘Desktop/’`

Comment: that command should error out? damn you @steeldriver :D

Comment: I think I did `mv Desktop/ls` as far as I remember. Is it worse?

Comment: still wouldn't work, `mv` needs two arguments

Comment: @nickborti dont think. proof it! see my answer: `history` will tell you

Comment: Also, unless you were working as root, `mv Desktop /` would give you a "permission denied" error

Comment: @Rinzwind aha. What I did was  `sudo mv Desktop/ ls` . There's a space after the slash. So `ls` is your second argument here. :D

Comment: there you go! but please add it to the question and Ill fix my answer ;)

Comment: @nickborti see the answer. What you did is just a beginner mistake but not as bad as it looks ;-) Totally and easily fixable.

Comment: @Rinzwind Dinner first! Lesson learnt! ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off: type

```
history
```

and look at the command you typed. Your desktop will be there where you moved it.

---

This

```
mv Desktop/ ls
```

then

```
mv ls Desktop
```

will fix it.

---

Adjust the command to what you see you did when typing `history`. When in doubt edit your question and add to it what you typed (or when even not sure of that post the last 20 odd lines `history` shows).

Comment: Unless `ls` was already a directory, of course, in which case you should `mv ls/Desktop ~`.

Comment: Also, `cd ~ls ; mv * ~/Desktop` is incorrect: presumably you mean `cd ~/ls`, and `*` will not match dotfiles.

Comment: @Rinzwind Your command worked and I can go to Desktop from terminal. But on startup it still shows the content of the Home Directory and not of the Desktop on the violet background.

Comment: please check 2 things: 1. make sure it is called `Desktop` and it is inside /home/$USER/ and do a `ls -l` and it looks like `drwxr-xr-x` and is owned and group set to your username.

Comment: It is. I checked. But the `Home` is showing. What am I missing?

Comment: check with `more ~/config/user-dirs.dirs` that it shows the correct location. and press f5 on the desktop too (just in case)

Comment: `more: stat of /home/nickborti/config/user-dirs.dirs failed: No such file or directory` is what it's showing.

Comment: @nickborti it needs a dot `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` [see this post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/745255/i-somehow-deleted-my-desktop-from-nautilus-places)  it should contain `XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"`

Comment: @Zanna That's efficient. :)

Comment: @nickborti you fixed it now? :)

Comment: @Zanna Yep. Had to reboot though. :)

Comment: Can you search where two directories you remember from desktop now are ?

Comment: @Narasimham which two directories?

Comment: @Narasimham sure. `locate {name}` If the dirs are new though you will need to `updated` the database 1st.